# Laravel elequent model/Relationship

Tags: laravel

**Say we have Conversation model** with columns

- id
- user_id
- user2_id
- updated_at
- etc

**user model** with

- id
- name
- etc

As you can see conversation has two participants id i.e user_id and user2_id one of the participants must be the current user,

So, i want to list conversations with the other participant name as the conversation name

how can i implement this??

Comment: Why would you like to implement a random insertion? That doesn't make sense

Comment: what im tryna do is creating a conversation table that have two participants,in each conversation one of the participant must be the current user and i want to list the conversations with the other participant as the conversation name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer i just need to make two relationships with different function name

```
class conversation extends Model
{
   use HasFactory;
   protected $fillable=['user_id','user2_id'];
   public function user1()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::Class, 'user_id');
    }
    public function user2()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::Class, 'user2_id');
    }
}
```

So when i retrieve i need to invoke this relationships in
controller.php

```
public function getConvs()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    return conversation::where([
        ['user_id', $user_id],
    ])->orwhere([
        ['user2_id', $user_id],
    ])->with('user2')->with('user1')->get();
}
```

in example.vue file

```
export default 
{    
    data(){
        return{
     
        convs_id: [],
        convs: [],
        }
    },
   
    created(){
       
        this.fetchConversation();
        t
    },
    methods:
    {
        
        fetchConversation()
        {
            axios.get('getConvs').then(response=>{
                this.convs = response.data;
                
            });
            
        }
    }
}
```

so in a view we can simply use like this

```
<li v-for="(conv, index) in convs" :key="index" class="pb-1">
                    
                       <div class="bg-yellow-100 p-2 m-2 rounded-lg" v-if="conv.user1.name == user.name"> <h1>{{conv.user2.name}}</h1></div>
                       <div class="bg-yellow-100 p-2 m-2 rounded-lg" v-else > <h1>{{conv.user2.name}}</h1></div>
            
                    </li>
```